# WHERE conditions work individually, but not when combined

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, where-clause

I have a query that is generating this error:

[image]

The code runs successfully when either `WHERE` condition is used, but when I combine them with the `OR` I get the following error :

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

I'm not sure how to interpret this. Can someone advise?

This is the whole code that generates the message:

```
SELECT
    tExceptionsAll1.ID,
    tExceptionsAll1.CardholderName,
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID,
    tExceptionsAll1.CardType, 
    tExceptionsAll1.Duration,
    tExceptionsAll1.ExceptionType,
    tExceptionsAll1.STL AS [Exp STL],
    tExceptionsAll1.CL AS [Exp CL], 
    tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL As [Exp TempSTL],
    tExceptionsAll1.TempCL As [Exp TempCL],
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card STL],
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card CL], 
    tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate,
    tExceptionsAll1.DCMNames,
    tExceptionsAll1.ReminderDate
FROM PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD
INNER JOIN tExceptionsAll1 
ON PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.CARD_ID = CLNG(tExceptionsAll1.CardID) 
AND CLNG(PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID) = tExceptionsAll1.CardholderUIN
WHERE
    (tExceptionsAll1.STL > 0 AND
    tExceptionsAll1.CL  > 0 AND
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT <> tExceptionsAll1.STL AND
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT <> tExceptionsAll1.CL  AND
    tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate IS NULL)
    OR 
    (tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL > 0 AND
    tExceptionsAll1.TempCL  > 0 AND
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT <> tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL AND
    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT <> tExceptionsAll1.TempCL AND
    tExceptionsAll1.TerminationDate IS NULL AND
    tExceptionsAll1.Duration like 'One-Time' AND
    tExceptionsAll1.ReminderDate < date());
```

Comment: take all the conditions out and start adding them one by one till you get the error

Comment: Are you certain that  tExceptionsAll1.STL, tExceptionsAll1.CL, tExceptionsAll1.TempSTL and tExceptionsAll1.TempCL are all numeric?

Answer (score 0):

This error means you're comparing two things that are of two incompatible types in the `WHERE` clause.

You should try deleting them one at a time to know where the problem is coming from.
Don't forget to save a copy of your original query though.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression/bde20c9b-4f68-4b78-b7c5-acde06e1242d)

Comment: oops.  the thing is, if I isolate the two portions of the WHERE clause before and after the OR and only keep that portion in the query, it runs successfully.  For both portions.  So the data types being compared in those clauses are the same and don't give me issue.  It's only when combining it all that I get an error.

Comment: @Katie, with your "combined" `WHERE` clause, try removing each of the expressions one-by-one until the error disappears. Then, when the troublesome expression is identified, you can focus your attention on that particular expression and progress the debugging effort.